# Regex anchor string

Tags: regex, powershell

I am working through a regex right now.  My issue is that my string could have 2 or 3 names in it.  I want to grab the first name and then the second and third as one string.

Here is the small powershell script:

```
$string = "ALDERS PAUL GERARD"
$string2 = "Alders Paul"

$pattern = '^(.*)\s(.*)$'



if($string -match $pattern){
    $last = $Matches[1]
    Write-Host "Success - $last"
}

if($string2 -match $pattern){
    $last = $Matches[1]
    Write-Host "Success - $last"
}
```

The results are Success - Alders Paul and Success - Alders

How can I make the regex anchor on the first space and not the second space in the line? So I get Success - Alders and Success - Alders

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use lazy matching with the first capturing group:

```
^(.*?)\s(.*)$
    ^
```

See [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/aC5kM2/2)

From [rexegg.com Lazy Quantifier Solution](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy_solution):

> The lazy `.*?` guarantees that the quantified dot only matches as many characters as needed for the rest of the pattern to succeed.

Or, use a non-whitespace shorthand class `\S` (i.e. matching any character but whitespace characters):

```
^(\S*)\s(.*)$
```

Here is a [second demo](https://regex101.com/r/aC5kM2/1)